Git repo for client's code
How should I manage source code repositories when doing web development for small clients?
I'm a freelancer doing web development for small clients and I’m wondering what the best practice is for managing the source code. Should I keep the code in my personal GitHub account, set up a GitHub organization for each client, or use some other approach? I'd like to ensure smooth collaboration and transfer of ownership if needed. What do other web developers typically do in this situation?

Sorry, I voted to close this question as its opinion based and out of scope here.

@davidgo I think it's important to know the different alternatives about OP's request.

the question is a bit vague.
The thing is, you can transfer ownership of a repository from a personal account in just a couple of clicks.
So it’s best to start from the client’s needs. If the client is a corporate entity, then set up the repository on their side, as a company.
In all other cases, a regular repository from your personal account will do just fine.
